# C# alternative for using enum as method parameter

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have the following method that downloads a set of item prices or license prices and stores it on the local HDD.
The only difference between the two is the input list that dictates what items that should be queried for. 
The application is being deployed as a clickonce app so the storage of the file differs from debug to deployment build.

```
    private const string PRICEFILE = "Resources\\prices.xml";
    private const string RATEFILE = "Resources\\rates.xml";
    private const string INPUTFILE = "Resources\\ItemsList.txt";
    private const string INPUTFILELICENSE = "Resources\\Licenses.txt";
    private const string LICENSEFILE = "Resources\\Licenses.xml";

   public string getFromInventoryTableOnServer(InventoryTypeEnum type)
    {
        string _input = "";
        string _output = "";
        // Get items from items file in resources
        if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
        {
            if (type.Equals(InventoryTypeEnum.Prices))
            {
                _input = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + @"\" + INPUTFILE;
                _output = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + @"\" + PRICEFILE;
            }
            else if (type.Equals(InventoryTypeEnum.Licences))
            {
                _input = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + @"\" + INPUTFILELICENSE;
                _output = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + @"\" + LICENSEFILE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (type.Equals(InventoryTypeEnum.Prices))
            {
                _input = INPUTFILE;
                _output = PRICEFILE;
            }
            else if (type.Equals(InventoryTypeEnum.Licences))
            {
                _input = INPUTFILELICENSE;
                _output = LICENSEFILE;
            }
        }


        // Read file
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(_input))
        {


            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                items.Add(sr.ReadLine().Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]);
            }

        }

        // Connection to database and table
        List<InventTableDW> it;
        using (AXDataContext ax = new AXDataContext())
        {
            var table = ax.GetTable<InventTableDW>();

            // Query AX for item info, specially prices
            var query =
                from p in table
                where items.Contains(p.ItemID) && p.ItemGroupID == "100"
                orderby p.ItemID
                select p;

            try
            {
                it = query.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
        }


        // Write to the price file
        try
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(_output))
            {
                {
                    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<InventTableDW>));
                    ser.Serialize(sw, it);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
        return "";
    }

enum InventoryTypeEnum
{
    Prices,
    Licences
}
```

I'm not very proud of the current implementation as it looks a bit messy. Do you have any improvement suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a good place to ask this particular question

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that site, I'll check it out.

Comment: The main alternative to using Enums (wich are little more then Grouped Compile time integer Constants) is a array, list or other collection. Somthing like a dictionary <int, soemthing> migth work better as you can easily do a key loockup to check if the input is valid.

Comment: you should probably just be storing these values in your webconfig, and then just using different build configuration to handle the switch for deployment

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are a good way to get rid of `if` or `switch` statements, but I don't like much the nested dictionaries solution proposed by Sam Axe. My solution uses only one `Dictionary`.

I have created a simple class that will be used as the key of the `Dictionary`, overriding both the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods:

```
internal class Key
{
    public readonly bool IsNetworkDeployed { get; }
    public readonly InventoryTypeEnum InventoryType { get; }

    public Key(InventoryTypeEnum inventoryType, bool isNetworkDeployed=false)
    {
        IsNetworkDeployed = isNetworkDeployed;
        InventoryType = inventoryType;
    }

    protected bool Equals(Key other)
    {
        return IsNetworkDeployed == other.IsNetworkDeployed && 
               InventoryType == other.InventoryType;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;

        return Equals((Key) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (IsNetworkDeployed.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ (int) InventoryType;
        }
    }
}
```

And, as suggested by Sam, a class to hold the paths:

```
public class FilePaths
{
    public string InputPath { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string OutputPath { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Initializing the `Dictionary`:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Key, FilePaths> _pathsDictionary = new Dictionary<Key, FilePaths>
{
    {
        new Key(InventoryTypeEnum.Licences, isNetworkDeployed: true),
        new FilePaths {
            InputPath = $@"{ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory}\{INPUTFILELICENSE}",
            OutputPath = $@"{ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory}\{LICENSEFILE}"
        }
    },
    {
        new Key(InventoryTypeEnum.Prices, isNetworkDeployed: true), 
        new FilePaths {
            InputPath = $@"{ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory}\{INPUTFILE}",
            OutputPath = $@"{ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory}\{PRICEFILE}"
        }
    },
    {
        new Key(InventoryTypeEnum.Licences, isNetworkDeployed: false), 
        new FilePaths {
            InputPath = INPUTFILELICENSE,
            OutputPath = LICENSEFILE
        }
    },
    {
        new Key(InventoryTypeEnum.Prices, isNetworkDeployed: false), 
        new FilePaths {
            InputPath = INPUTFILE,
            OutputPath = PRICEFILE
        }
    }
};
```

Using the code:

```
public string GetFromInventoryTableOnServer(InventoryTypeEnum type)
{
    var key = new Key(type, ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed);
    FilePaths paths = _pathsDictionary[key];

    // remaining code here ...
}
```

Comment: I like this.  Its a little more setup, but i think it provides a very nice interface.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of a lookup might make the code more "pretty".  Though the effect on maintainability may be dubious.  You would need to remember to update the `_pathMap` variable whenever a path changed.  Shouldn't be a big deal.. you have to change them *somewhere*.

Also, I don't care for the `bool` key, but I tried to keep it as close to your original function as possible.  The `bool` doesn't instantly convey intent.  I would recommend changing it to an enum if at all possible.

```
private class FilePaths {
    public FilePaths(string inputPath, string outputPath) { 
        InputPath = inputPath;
        OutputPath = outputPath;
    }
    public string InputPath {get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string OutputPath {get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

enum InventoryTypeEnum {
    Prices,
    Licences
}

private const string PRICEFILE = "Resources\\prices.xml";
private const string RATEFILE = "Resources\\rates.xml";
private const string INPUTFILE = "Resources\\ItemsList.txt";
private const string INPUTFILELICENSE = "Resources\\Licenses.txt";
private const string LICENSEFILE = "Resources\\Licenses.xml";

private Dictionary<bool, Dictionary<InventoryTypeEnum, FilePaths>> _pathMap = 
    new Dictionary<bool, Dictionary<InventoryTypeEnum, FilePaths>>() {
        { true, { InventoryTypeEnum.Prices, 
                  new FilePaths(
                      ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + @"\" + INPUTFILE,
                      ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + @"\" + PRICEFILE
                  ) 
        } },
        { true, { InventoryTypeEnum.Licences, 
                  new FilePaths(
                      ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + @"\" + INPUTFILELICENSE,
                      ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + @"\" + LICENSEFILE
                  ) 
        } },
        { false, { InventoryTypeEnum.Prices, 
                  new FilePaths(
                      INPUTFILE,
                      PRICEFILE
                  ) 
        } },
        { false, { InventoryTypeEnum.Licenses, 
                  new FilePaths(
                      INPUTFILELICENSE,
                      LICENSEFILE
                  ) 
        } }
    }

public string getFromInventoryTableOnServer(InventoryTypeEnum type) {
    FilePaths paths = _pathMap[ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed][type];
    // paths.InputPath and paths.OutputPath should now hold the correct values.

    //  ... rest of function ...
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to use a `ValueTuple<bool, InventoryType>` as key, instead of the nested `Dictionary`s you propose.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll look into it and test a little bit.

Comment: A `Dictionary<bool,... >` can only have a maximum of *two* entries: one with a key of `true`, the other `false`. How are you adding four values?  You'd have to remove one each of the extra true/false and then remove/reposition some of the braces to get all the values into the nested dictionaries. Otherwise this would throw an exception I believe

Comment: @SamAxe why would you have them do all these if statements, wouldn't it make more sense to handle this, using the build configuration,  appsettings.json or using   web.config

Comment: @pinkfloydx33pi you're absolutely correct.  The initializer wont work here.  Thats what i get for writing without testing.  One could move the initialization to a method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, move the nested `if`s to a separate method that returns a `ValueTuple<string, string>`. From there on you have a few options, I would like to propose one with a switch.

I think it's best to check for the enum first, in case it will grow in the future, and then check for the boolean. Like this:

```
enum Animal
{
    Fish,
    Dog,
    Zebra
}

string GetLabel(bool isAwesome, Animal animal)
{
    switch (animal)
    {
        case Animal.Fish:
            return isAwesome ? "awesome fish" : "not so awesome fish";
        case Animal.Dog:
            return isAwesome ? "super awesome dog" : "awesome dog";
        case Animal.Zebra:
            return isAwesome ? "awesome zebra" : "normal zebra";
        default:
            return "is this even an animal?";
    }
}
```

Not that this is more performant than the nested `Dictionary`s proposed in another answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, performance is not an issue here, more maintainability and readability so this is a good suggestion.